# How to prevent notification bar's scrolling-animation on new Notification

Tags: android, notifications

Can I create notification that will simply appear on the Notification Bar without it's animation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Set the `tickerText` field of your `Notification` object to `null`.